# What is the average size of a billboard?

Tags: billboard, outdoors

So what is the average size of a billboard? I'm using Corel Draw x6 and would like to know the *average size* of them.

[image: Billboard]

Comment: "outdoor" isn't a noun in English. The word is indeed billboard. I edited your question.

Comment: Billboard sizes differ by country because of local laws/legistlation - there's information on various standard sizes used internationally [here](http://www.papersizes.org/billboard-sizes.htm).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for USA, I am unsure of other countries billboard standards.

14' H x 48' W is common for traditional print billboards.

Some other sizes

> Standard Sizes
>
> - 14' H x 48' W
> - 10’ H x 40’ W
> - 10’6” H x 36’ W
>
> Spectacular Sizes
>
> - 20’ H x 60’ W
> - 16’ H x 60’ W

Source:  [OAAA - Bulletins](https://oaaa.org/AboutOOH/OOHBasics/OOHMediaFormats/Bulletins.aspx)

A digital billboard will have different specs.

Companies own billboards, so if you want to place an ad at a certain location then you contact who owns that billboard. They will then give you specs on that particular billboard.